# Future method not being invoked

Tags: future

I have created a future method that will update accounts in seperate batches. The client sometimes gets a CPU timeout.
Anyway, my future method is not being invoked. 
Does anyone have an idea why?

```
public class accountInformationList
    {
        Map<Id,accountInformation> accounts     { get; set; }
    }

public class accountInformation
{
    public String   BillingStreetNew        { get; set; }
    public String   BillingCityNew          { get; set; }
    public String   BillingCountryNew       { get; set; }
    public String   BillingPostalCodeNew    { get; set; }
    public String   BillingstateNew         { get; set; }
}


public void updateAccounts( List<Account> newAccounts )
{
    Integer startInd    = 0;
    while( newAccounts.size( ) > 0 )
    {
        accountInformationList  accountInformation  = new accountInformationList( );
        accountInformation.accounts                 = new Map<Id, accountInformation>( );

        Integer endInd                              = 0;
        Integer index                               = 0;

        for ( endInd = 0; endInd < 50; ++endInd )
        {
            index       = startInd + endInd;
            if ( index < newAccounts.size( ) )
            {
                if ( index > 50 )
                {
                    newAccounts[index].Name.addError( 'This account will be updated in a seperate batch.' );
                    accountInformation  acctInfo    = new accountInformation( );
                    acctInfo.BillingStreetNew       = newAccounts[index].BillingStreet;
                    acctInfo.BillingCityNew         = newAccounts[index].BillingCity;
                    acctInfo.BillingCountryNew      = newAccounts[index].BillingCountry;
                    acctInfo.BillingPostalCodeNew   = newAccounts[index].BillingPostalCode;
                    acctInfo.BillingStatenew        = newAccounts[index].BillingState;
                    accountInformation.accounts.put( newAccounts[index].Id, acctInfo );
                }
            } else break;
        }
        System.Debug( 'total size of the accounts: ' + accountInformation.accounts.keySet( ).size( ) );
        if ( accountInformation.accounts.keySet( ).size( ) > 0 )
        {
            String j = JSON.serialize( accountinformation );
            System.Debug( 'JSON: ' + j );
            try
            {
                tidyUpAccounts( j );
            } catch ( Exception exc )
            {

            }
        }
        if ( index >= ( newAccounts.size( ) - 1 ) )
            break;
        else startInd += endInd;
    }
}

@future public static void tidyUpAccounts( String accountString )
{
    accountInformationList  accountInfo = ( accountInformationList )JSON.deserialize( accountString, accountInformationList.class );
    List<Account> accounts              = new List<Account>( );

    accounts    = [SELECT Id, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingPostalCode, BillingState FROM Account WHERE Id IN : accountInfo.accounts.keySet( )];

    for ( Account account : accounts )
    {
        accountInformation acc      = accountInfo.accounts.get( account.Id );
        account.BillingStreet       = acc.BillingStreetNew;
        account.BillingCity         = acc.BillingCityNew;
        account.BillingCountry      = acc.BillingCountryNew;
        account.BillingState        = acc.BillingStateNew;
        account.BillingPostalCode   = acc.BillingPostalCodeNew;
    }

    update accounts;
}
```

Comment: Put a debug in the catch block and see if there is an error that issuing thrown. Have you reviewed the debug logs. Up to what part of your code have you confirmed is working? Is UpdateAccounts being executed?

Comment: I condirmed in the debug logs that the JSON is generated and if I put something just behind the call, it will also run.

Comment: When you put a debug statement in the catch block and report the results we can help you further. Either it is being run and you are looking at the wrong place, or there is an error and it is being caught.

Comment: I already tried that ;) 
the weird thing is, with my code slightly changed, it is working so I'm afraid I'll have to retrace my steps :(

Comment: What did you change to make it work, and what did the debug show

Comment: the try-catch would be more useful if it surrounded the whole method, rather than just the future method invocation